# Typescript generics - is "extends object" pointless? What is the best practice?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've noticed that `<P extends object>` generic is usually pointless because basically everything in javascript is an object. Most literals are objects with .toString method. A string is an object with a .length property, etc. I've come to prefer just `<P>` but curious what others have noticed.

I don't have a good example right now, I'm more just trying to hear about other people's experience.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where `extends object` wouldn't be redundant, but I'd be interested in learning otherwise.

Comment: Actually, [`string` does not extend `object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgeQEYCsA8AVKE7AgOwBMBnKAe1QgGNgA+KAXigwCgXRJmJjhHZFUaHgCcAlvgDmtFkA), although `String` does. I'm voting to close because the question seems to be based on a false premise.

Comment: `<P extends any>` is also a workaround for tsx files to prevent <P> from being interpreted as a JSX tag (though can image using object instead of any). Can't really weigh in if it's pointless. I'd imagine if `P extends object` and you trying to pass a number as P it would not allow it though

Comment: For the TSX workaround: `<P,>` also works without introducing a constraint

Comment: Just for more detail, I've noticed situations where typescript interprets a string as an object and then I have all these wonky keys of such an object (`toString | valueOf | toNumber | ...`). Also @jcalz, thank you for the in-depth answer! I've been generally assuming that `object` and `{}` are the same, and had no idea that `Object` was an actual type

Comment: In said situation where I was using `P extends object` or `P extends {}`, and I was seeing strings/numbers being interpreted as objects, removing the `extends object/{}` fixed it. If I can recall/dig up what that code was I will be sure to share it back here, but it'll probably be a while until I happen to be working on the right code that jogs my memory.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

See ["The `object` Type in TypeScript"](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-object-type-in-typescript) for more information.

The [`object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) in TypeScript was introduced specifically to exclude the seven [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) types, `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `bigint`, `symbol`, `undefined`, and `null`.  (Yes, `typeof null === "object"` at runtime, but it is still considered primitive in JS and TS).  It is true that `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `bigint`, and `symbol` values will be automatically wrapped in `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `BigInt`, and `Symbol` objects (respectively) when you access members on them as if they were objects.  But they *are* distinguishable from true objects, and sometimes this makes a difference.  The example given in the TypeScript Handbook is the [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), which leads to runtime errors if passed an argument of a primitive type (except for `null`).  Hence TypeScript's typing for `Object.create()` specifies that its argument is of type `object | null`.  If you want your generic parameter to exclude primitives, `<P extends object>` would be the right way to do it... so it isn't pointless.

Note that there is also an `Object` interface in TypeScript, starting with an uppercase `O`. This interface contains the (apparent) members that exist on everything in JS, like `valueOf()` and `toString()`.  It might be closer to what you were thinking of when you said "everything is an object"; only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `Object`.  Generally speaking, though, [you probably don't want to use the `Object` type in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object); such wrapper types are hardly ever what people want to use.

If you really want to capture "anything which can be indexed into like an object", you should probably use the so-called "empty object" type, `{}`.  This is an object type with no known properties, and behaves like `Object`.  Again, only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `{}`.  In fact, it used to be the case that unconstrained generic type parameters (like `<P>` instead of `<P extends Q>`) were implicitly constrained to `{}`.  So it used to be quite literally useless to write `<P extends {}>`.

Since TypeScript 3.5, however, [unconstrained generics are now given an implicit constraint of `unknown` instead of `{}`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/23a53b8b7a9f0be7c12beab241fd1423a2336898/Breaking-Changes.md#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown).  The [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) type really is "everything" in TypeScript.  You can assign any value whatsoever to a variable of type `unknown` (but not vice-versa).  It is truly pointless to write `<P extends unknown>`.

And we might as well end with [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), the ultimate "anything-goes" type.  Not only can you assign anything to `any` (like `unknown`), you can also assign `any` to anything (like `never`).  Using `any` is like throwing up your hands and giving up; it's more of a disabling of type checking than it is an actual type. [Since TypeScript 3.9](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#type-parameters-that-extend-any-no-longer-act-as-any), writing `<P extends any>` is the same as writing `<P extends unknown>`, and therefore, similarly pointless.  (It used to be that `<P extends any>` allowed you to treat `P` like `any` when `P` was unresolved, like in a generic function implementation, but that was considered silly and changed.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdE4AjAK02gD4AKbALkTQEpEBvRAXwChg6AIkGsA3IgD0ErACcZcGfzpgQAG1Xsps+YoEdum6XADWAQwCevfuGjwkAc3RZc+YogDylalHpMW7Lj57IRFJIzNLYJV1Q20FXmD9WJMLK1BIWAREAAsnHDxCEn1fZjZOHl5skOSIyuU1DTC4xSqkppTLawy7RBg8l0LEcGMwOAB3MBL-cr4YavbauejGrQ7eObbV2rSbTKQKfoK3UzBzKbLA3gp5rdTr5Zq7uk3w1N4gA)

Comment: Wonderful and thoughtful reply which exhaustively covers the entire topic of interest the enquirer is interested in. Thanks! Learned a lot more than I was searching for! - Especially loved your definition of `any` :-D

Comment: ```you can also assign any to anything (like never)```

It seems to be incorrect. [Here is a playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2IBuIBOAoUkBGcrwE8IBeCAFnXShImwG4g)

Comment: For completeness: `type T1 = null extends object ? true : false` does return `true` if `strictNullChecks` is not enabled (same for `undefined`) .