# Why does a union of type literals and (string & {}) cause IDE code completion while allowing all strings?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I want to allow any `string`, but want to get code completion for some special color values I defined. To accomplish this, I recently got to see the following trick:

```
type Color = 'primary' | 'secondary' | (string & {});
const color1: Color = 'other'; // any string is allowed
const color2: Color = 'primary' // code completion offered
```

By adding `(string & {})` (just adding `string & {}` without round brackets also works because `&` probably has precedence over `|` in TS I guess) to a union of string literals I can assign any string but will get code completion support in my IDE for the string literals 'primary' and 'secondary'.

I don't understand WHY this works! What is the actual type of the intersection `string & {}` (it seems to be a `string` but given the code completion it provides it seems to be more...) and why does adding it to the union provide us with code completion?

```
// What is the actual type of `StringCombo`?
type StringCombo = string & {};

// Error: "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'"
const combo: StringCombo = {};
```

---

Own investigations:

Note that a union with just `string` (not `string & {}`) does not provide me with any code completion (I think the resulting type is just `string`). Neither does `string & { [key: string]: any }` do the trick:

```
// Like about but without IDE code completion for 'primary', 'secondary'
type ColorJustString = 'primary' | 'secondary' | string;
// Doesn't work
type ColorAlternative = 'primary' | 'secondary' | string & { [key: string]: any };
const color3: ColorJustString = 'other';
const color4: ColorAlternative = 'other'; // Type '"other"' is not assignable to type 'ColorAlternative'
```

According to [this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945966/3210677) `{}` can be defined as:

> [...] The "empty object" type `{}` is an object type with no known properties, and behaves like `Object`. Again, only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `{}`.

However, this definition doesn't help me to figure out why `string & {}` creates the described behavior...

[TypeScript Playground for my question](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: It's equivalent to `string` but the compiler doesn't aggressively *reduce* it because intersecting primitives with object types is used [to simulate nominal types ("branding")](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) in a different use case.  The lack of aggressive reduction means that `(string & {}) | "a"` persists as-is, and then the compiler sees `"a"`.  It's a workaround using a feature meant for other purposes.

Comment: @jcalz Why does `{}` (i.e. `string & {}`) enable this behavior but `string & {__brand: "A"}` which you mention as an example of "branding" in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65908955/3210677) does not? E.g. `string & { __brand: "A" }; | 'a'` will only allow `'a'`. See [this TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwMIHsC2AjTAjFALxQDkAhmVAD5QDOCKqUAZFAN4C+A3AFABjTMkZRgERgQBcsJmix5CJKACIAFhAA2mzCr59QkWUnk58AJmWVqdRiZbsOUAPrPc8CsgAmMlQEEVKF5BYVFxRnMZOHsFC2UVChV+IRFgMQlgAGYouQwzTEtSFVwkqAB6MqgAUXh4THgZABVwaDJilWpEeihkTDSKenpEVGQKXE1oYEwxFvJo5liCsiA)

Comment: Because `{__brand: "A"}` is a different type from `{}`?  `string` is assignable to `string & {}` but not to `string & {__brand: "A"}`.  Branding is a different use case entirely from what you're doing here.  The compiler often does *reduction* whereby something like `string & never` is reduced to `never` immediately, or `string & unknown` is reduced to `string` immediately.  The reason the compiler does not do this with intersections of primitives and object types is to support branding; technically `string & {__brand: "A"}` should be `never`, but doing that breaks branding.

Comment: I can write up an answer if that makes sense to you, otherwise please let me know what you don't find clear so I can address it.

Comment: @jcalz That helps! Still unclear: Why is `string` assignable to `string & {}` but not to `string & {__brand: "A"}`? Both should technically reduce to `never` but they don't. What's so special about `{}` that causes it to be treated so differently when intersecting it with a primitive? What's so different about `{__brand: "A"}` in this context? In general, how does the TS compiler treat an object type in such intersections? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945966/3210677) you wrote that only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `{}`. How is this property used in such intersections?

Comment: Since `string` is neither `null` not `undefined`, then it is assignable to `{}`.  And it is definitely assignable to `string` itself.  By definition of intersection, then, `string` is assignable to `string & {}` because it is assignable to each member of the intersection.  Primitives which are auto-wrapped with objects in JavaScript upon being index into are treated by TypeScript as assignable to those wrapper object types.  So `string extends String` is true (the reverse is not).  The object type `{}` has no known properties, so by structural subtyping, has nothing incompatible with `String`.

Comment: So `string extends String` is true and `String extends {}` is true, so `string extends {}` is true (by transitivity of `extends` which is not always followed in TS but here it is).  On the other hand, `String` is not known to have a `__brand` property of type `"A"`, so `String extends {__brand: "A"}` is false, so `string extends {__brand: "A"}` is false, so `string extends string & {__brand: "A"}` is false.

Comment: I hope this is making sense to you.  Note that `string extends {length: number}` is true because if I have a `string` value `s` and index into it with a key named `length`, then you will get a value of type `number` (e.g., `s.length * 3` is a valid thing to write in TypeScript).  Anyway, `string & {}` should *not* reduce to `never`; if anything it should reduce to `string` because `string` is a subtype of `string`.  You only want `A & B` to reduce to `never` if there are no values which are both `A` and `B`.  But a value like `"hello"` is both a `string` and a `{}`.

Comment: I want to write up an answer, but I don't know that all the detail will be useful. The sketch looks like:  `string | "a"` is aggressively reduced to `string` by the compiler.  On the other hand, `(string & {}) | "a"` does not collapse to `string` because the compiler leaves intersections of primitives and object types alone without trying to reduce them or further refactor them in order to support a different feature known as branding. Since `(string & {})` is kept as-is, then `(string & {}) | "a"` persists in this form, despite being equivalent to `string`.  Does that work for you?